# Can I use Direct3D to generate thumbnails?

Tags: directx, direct3d, directx-9, direct3d9

I can use `D3DXCreateTextureFromFile` to load an image, and `D3DXSaveTextureToFile` to save it, but how can I resize it? Should I use `IDirect3DDevice9::SetRenderTarget` and render to a texture?

Is it slower than doing it on CPU?

Answer (score 1):

Generally you 'resize' images with the GPU by drawing them as a 'fullscreen quad' onto a render target set to the target size. Depending on the size and the data involved, it's probably slower to ship it over the GPU and then rely on readback to get it to disk so doing it on the CPU is usually the better approach. I believe the legacy deprecated `D3DX9` utility library you are using can do the resize with `D3DXLoadSurfaceFromSurface`.

> You should not be using Direct3D 9 and/or the legacy `D3DX9` library for new projects. See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee663275.aspx) and [Living without D3DX](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2013/08/20/living-without-d3dx/)

A better solution is to use the Windows Imaging Component directly to load the image, resize it, and save a thumbnail. See [DirectXTex](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTex) for extensive example code using WIC.

Comment: In what version of windows the "Windows Imaging Component" first appeared? My computer is pretty old.